# Firebase Cloud Firestore Design

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble finishing the design for a android application I am working on. I have three main groups that I need to store data in; Hosts, Volunteers, and Events. The problem I am running into is that most events will have more than one volunteer, and I do not know how I should structure the collections so I can query my database for all events created by a host and for all volunteers within each event.

I currently have 3 top level collections; Hosts, Volunteers, and Events. However, I am wondering if this is actually the best way to go about this, and can someone explain how to query the database for all volunteers within each event with this design.

If this is not the best way to do it, then I would appreciate it if someone could explain another approach and how it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently have 3 top level collections

That's a common way for structuring a Cloud Firestore database.

> can someone explain how to query the database for all volunteers within each event with this design.

A possible database structure might be:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- volunteers (collection)
  |    |
  |    --- volunteerId (document)
  |          |
  |          --- //Volunteer properties
  |          |
  |          --- eventIds: ["generatedEventId", "generatedEventId"]
  |
  --- events (collection)
       |
       --- eventId (document)
             |
             --- //Event properties
```

As you can see I have added the `eventId` as a value within `eventIds` array, since a `volunteer` can participate at more than one event. To get all volunteers within each event, you can use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference volunteersRef = rootRef.collection("volunteers");
Query query = volunteersRef.whereArrayContains("eventIds", "generatedEventId");
```

Where the `generatedEventId` is the id of event you at which the volunteers are participating.

Since you didn't choose a tag for a platform, I have wrote the above lines of code in Android but it can be simply written also for other programming languages.

Comment: How does that query work? I understand the second line, but  I do not understand how the next line works though. And yes, I am using Android Studio. I'm sorry I should've put that in the question.

Comment: About which line are you talking about?

Comment: The final line.

Comment: @NoahAnderson The last line of code means that you are first geeting a reference to the `volunteers` collection and then you are trying to find all events at which a volunteer participate, right?

Comment: oh okay so I think I understand what you're saying. Basically every document within the volunteer collection will have a array storing every event they have signed up for then you are searching the events collection for events with matching eventIDs. Is that correct?